# algebraic binary operations that are associative and nice in a way.

Tags: symmetric-functions

It is well known that
$$ a*b = ab + a + b$$
and
$$ x*y = \dfrac{x+y}{1-xy} $$
are commutative associative binary operations.
What rational function $f$ is a commutative associative binary operations that satisfy (informally writing)
$$ a_1*a_2*\cdots*a_n = f(e_0,e_1,e_2,\cdots,)$$
where $e_i$s are elementary symmetric polynomials and thought of as $e_i=0$ if $i\geq n+1$ and $e_0=1$.

Or more formally, There is a sequence of rational functions $(f_i)_i$ that satisfy
$$ f_i(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_i) = f_{i+1}(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_i,a_{i+1})$$
and
$$ a_1*a_2*\cdots a_n = f_n(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n).$$

Comment: Not sure if it's useful, but I just wanted to note that both of your examples are of the form $h^{-1}(h(a)+h(b))$ for some bijection $h$. In the first, case $h(x)=x+1$, and in the second case, $h(x)=\tan^{-1}(x)$.

Answer (score 3):

The operations can be represented by bijection of the real numbers, applying an operation there, and then transforming back again.

For example, in the case of

$$a*b=ab+a+b$$

first apply $f(x) = x+1$ to both $a$ and $b$, then apply multiplication as usual, and then  apply $f^{-1} = x-1$:

$$a*b=f^{-1}(f(a)f(b)) = (a+1)(b+1) - 1 = ab+a+b$$

That is we have the commutative diagram

$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
(\Bbb R^*,*) @>>> (\Bbb R^*,*) \\
@VV{f}V @V{f}VV \\
(\Bbb R^\times,\cdot) @>>> (\Bbb R^\times,\cdot) \\
\end{CD}$$

which describes a bijective homomorphism (ispmorphism) of two (infinite, abelian, Lie) groups that can be written

$$f(a*b) = f(a)\cdot f(b)$$

In particular, the mapping carries over group properties like:

**Neutral Element:** $f$ maps $0$ to $1$, and hence $0$ is the neutral element of the group $(\Bbb R^*,*)$ since $a*0 = a\cdot0 +a+0 = a$.

**Inverse Elements:** $f$ maps $-1$ to $0$, a real number that has no multiplicative inverse, thus only $\Bbb R^\times=\Bbb R\backslash\{0\}$ is a group under multiplication but $\Bbb R$ isn't.  Consequently, $\Bbb R$ is not a group under $*$ but only $\Bbb R^*=\Bbb R\backslash\{-1\}$, because $a*(-1) = -1$ for all $a$, which has no inverse element. The inverse of $a\in(\Bbb R^*,*)$ is $a^{-1}=\dfrac1{a+1}-1=-\dfrac a{a+1}$ since $$a*a^{-1}= a\left(-\frac a{a+1}\right)+a-\frac a{a+1}=0$$ and $0$ is the neutral element.

**Associativity**: $$\begin{align}
(a*b)*c &= f^{-1}(f(a*b)f(c)) \\
&= f^{-1}(f(a)f(b)f(c)) \\
&= f^{-1}(f(a)f(b*c)) = a*(b*c)
\end{align}$$

---

The second mapping
$$x*y = \frac{x+y}{1-xy}$$

is realized by $f(x) = \arctan x$ due to addition theorem of arctan

$$\arctan x + \arctan y = \arctan \frac{x+y}{1-xy}$$
resp.

$$\tan(x+y) = \frac{\tan x+ \tan y}{1-\tan x \tan y}$$

This means you can first apply arctan and then addition, or alternatively first apply $*$ and then arctan.  This also establishes an isomorphism or groups, one is $(\Bbb R,+)$ and the other is $((-\pi/2,\pi/2),*)$.

---

The $n$-fold operations can then be expressed by the associated operation.  For the 1st case:

$$\begin{align}
{\Huge*}_{k=1}^n a_k
&= f^{-1}\left(\prod_{k=1}^nf(a_k)\right) \\
&= -1+ \prod_{k=1}^n(1+a_k) \\
\end{align}$$

---

One of the most prominent and useful such isomorphism is the the isomorphism between $(\Bbb R^+,\cdot)$ and $(\Bbb R,+)$ mediated by $\ln$ and $\exp$ (or any log-exp pair to some other basis like 10)

$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
(\Bbb R^+,\cdot) @>>> (\Bbb R^+,\cdot) \\
@VV{\ln}V @A{\exp}AA \\
(\Bbb R,+) @>>> (\Bbb R,+) \\
\end{CD}$$

using

$$\log_b(xy) = \log_b x + \log_b y \quad\text{ resp. }\quad b^{x+y}=b^xb^y$$

that is, instead of multiplication (expensive) you can first apply log then add the values, then inverse log.  The latter three operations can be performed using a slide-rule, or log and exp can be performed using lookup-tables.  This method lost significance with the advent of modern computes, but was very important in earlier times.

Answer (score 0):

Another example is
$$x*y=\frac{x+y}{1+xy}\tag{1}$$
which, like your
$$x*y=\frac{x+y}{1-xy}\tag{2}$$
has the property
$h(x*y)=h(x)+h(y)$
for some invertible function $h$. As [the earlier answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4505229) pointed out, with $(2)$, $h$ is arctan; with $(1)$, $h$ is arctanh.

With $(2)$, $\infty$ is in the range (when the denominator is 0) and so must be in the domain and codomain, to keep $*$ closed. With $(1)$, a similar approach is possible; alternatively, you could set the domain to be $(-1, 1)$, as $*$ is closed on $(-1, 1)$.